# Export site configuration from WebMatrix to host under IIS7 (trying to host Umbraco)

Tags: iis-7, configuration, umbraco, webmatrix

How do I export web site settings from WebMatrix so that I can host the same web site under IIS7?

I am trying to host an Umbraco web-site and I have it working using WebMatrix, but when I try to host it under IIS there are all sort of things not configured properly.

Comment: That's odd. What kind of things are not configured correctly? AFAIK there's no reason taking a WebMatrix site and running it under IIS shouldn't work...